# User in multiple categories MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have been searching for a good day for a way to search for a user that is in each category AND the next not OR.

```
user_id
------- 
1
2
3
4
```

table_user_categories

```
user_id|category_id
-------------
1      |1
1      |2
2      |1
2      |3
```

So I want to ask MySQL, who is in category 1 AND 2. I have tried the IN(1,2) approach but this, as I understand it is OR not AND giving me the results of user_id 1 and 2 not just 1.

Its also quite important for this to be extensible as it can be as there are about 15 categories, so i'll need to add more into the query the more the user selects in my interface.

Huge apologies for anything I've missed in my post here, always easier to think of these things as opposed to asking.

I just dug out an old version of what I was trying - was just going to post this to compare...

```
SELECT u.user_id, COUNT(*) AS category_count
FROM table_user_categories AS u
WHERE u.category_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY u.user_id
HAVING category_count = 2;
```

Comment: I spot some differences with the distinct category_id, so will try yours out and get back to you. Thanks so much for your speedy reply. If its all good of course, i'll up vote it and accept it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find all the user_ids that have both (or, generally, all) the given categories, you can use aggregation with filtering:

```
select user_id
from table_user_categories
where category_id in (1, 2)
group by user_id
having count(distinct category_id) = 2;
```

The `having` in above clause make sure that only user_id with both category_id 1 *and* 2 are returned.